# Dependent Chained Dropdown Select List with Django - Not working

Tags: python, django, ajax, forms, dropdown

I am trying to build a dependant dropdown in a django form, but it is not working. I have followed videos and tutorials, but got no luck.

I would like to select a brand of a car (make) and then a model of a car. The model depends on the car's brand, of course.

I have followed this tutorial https://python.plainenglish.io/python-and-django-create-a-dependent-chained-dropdown-select-list-b2c796f5a11

Status: The "Make" dropdown works fine. The "Model" dropdown is never showing anything.
It just does not work, but no error is shown... :S

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    make = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    model = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...omitted
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Vehicle
import json    

def readJson(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        return json.load(fp)

def get_make():
    """ GET MAKE SELECTION """
    filepath = '/Users/alvarolozanoalonso/desktop/project_tfm/tfm/JSON/make_model_A.json'
    all_data = readJson(filepath)
    all_makes = [('-----', '---Select a Make---')]

    for x in all_data:
        if (x['make_name'], x['make_name']) in all_makes:
            continue
            else:
                y = (x['make_name'], x['make_name'])
                all_makes.append(y)

# here I have also tried "all_makes.append(x['make_name'])

    
            return all_makes
    

class VehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    make = forms.ChoiceField(
                    choices = get_make(),
                    required = False,
                    label='Make:',
                    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'id_make'}),
                    )
...omitted



    class Meta:
            model = Vehicle
            fields = ['make', 'is_new', 'body_type', 'fuel_type', 'exterior_color', 'transmission', 'wheel_system', 'engine_type',
                      'horsepower', 'engine_displacement', 'mileage', 'transmission_display', 'year', 'fuel_tank_volume',
                      'city_fuel_economy', 'highway_fuel_economy', 'maximum_seating']
```

model.HTML

```
{% block javascript %}
<script>
          $("#id_make").change(function () {
              var makeId = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'get-model' %}",
                data: {
                  'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                  'make': makeId,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data.models);
                  let html_data = '<option value="">-------</option>';
                  data.models.forEach(function (data) {
                      html_data += `<option value="${data}">${data}</option>`
                  });
                  $("#id_model").html(html_data);
                }
              });
});
</script>
{% endblock javascript %}

<form class="" action="" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for error in errors  %}
          <div class="alert alert-danger mb-4" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          <div class="form-row">

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label>Status:</label>
                {{ form.make }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
              <label >Model:</label>
              <select id="id_model" class="form-control" name="state">
                <option value="-----">Select Model</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            
            ...omitted

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

views.py

```
def model(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'GET':
           form  = VehicleForm()
           context['form'] = form
           return render(request, 'model.html', context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = VehicleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'model.html', context)

def getModel(request):
    make = request.POST.get('make')
    models = return_model_by_make(make)
    return JsonResponse({'models': models})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your change handler for `id_make` is attached before the select is created in the DOM, so your event handler does not fire.
You can use event delegation to set up an event handler before an element is created

```
  $(document).on('change', "#id_make", function () {
      var makeId = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'get-model' %}",
        data: {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
          'make': makeId,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data.models);
          let html_data = '<option value="">-------</option>';
          data.models.forEach(function (data) {
              html_data += `<option value="${data}">${data}</option>`
          });
          $("#id_model").html(html_data);
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Musa! Unfortunately it is not working... :S I tried your code both before and after select creation but it isn't working. Should I share the whole project on github?

Comment: You can send a link to the page and I'll see if I can spot what's wrong

Comment: Hi Again Musa, I have my project on github and changed it to be public for a couple of days so you can see it. Thank you very much! https://github.com/alvarico509/TFM